# delayed job not performing after being enqued, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I did this in controller:

```
MyTestJob.perform_later
```

When this is called, this is displayed in my rails console:

```
[ActiveJob] Enqueued MyTestJob (Job ID: e7af2684-4dc4-4a1f-bac7-b189dddb6f2f) to DelayedJob(default)
[ActiveJob]    (0.4ms)  BEGIN
[ActiveJob]   SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "public"."delayed_jobs" ("queue", "handler", "run_at", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["queue", "default"], ["handler", "--- !ruby/object:ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper\njob_data:\n  job_class: GenerateCouponcodesJob\n  job_id: e7af2684-4dc4-4a1f-bac7-b189dddb6f2f\n  queue_name: default\n  arguments: []\n"], ["run_at", "2015-10-28 09:58:17.891850"], ["created_at", "2015-10-28 09:58:17.892095"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-28 09:58:17.892095"]]
[ActiveJob]    (11.0ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered campaign/test.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 254ms (Views: 233.6ms | ActiveRecord: 12.0ms)
```

SO the above log says that job is enqued (which proves my delayed job worker is working fine), but it is not getting performed,
here is my job:

```
class MyTestJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    directory = Rails.root
    File.open(File.join(directory, 'file.txt'), 'w') do |f|
        f.puts "contents"
    end
    Delayed::Worker.logger.debug("Log Entry")
  end
end
```

No file created and no log created in delayed_job.log.
I have done everything correctly but still, there are no error as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the above log says that job is enqueued (which proves my delayed job worker is working fine)

Nope. This means that the "enqueuer" is working fine. Says nothing about the worker.

It should be run as a separate process.

```
bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

Comment: oh.. can the jobs run automatically or I have to run this command everytime I need to perform a job?

Comment: and how to empty my queue?

Comment: Just launch the worker and it'll sit there, waiting for the jobs.